# Calculating rank in EF Core 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table in which I want to calculate the rank of my data based on **Amount**.

```
var result = await context.Table
                 .Select(i => new Table {
                     Rank = // want to calculate the rank based on amount
                 }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Amount)
                 .ToListAsync();
```

I tried using the element index but for that, I need to fetch all the data to the client first.

Comment: Do you mean rank as in `RANK(amount) OVER(...)`

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct implementation for RANK() in EF. You are better off with using a custom LINQ query to do what you want, like,

```
var query = from t in context.Table
    orderby t.Amount descending
    select new 
    {
        Rank = (from o in context.Table
                where o.Amount > s.Amount
                select o).Count() + 1 
    };
```

If you know the SQL query you want to execute, you can create a custom function or stored procedure and then execute it using Entity Framework. Please refer [this](https://www.codemag.com/Article/2101031/Calling-Stored-Procedures-with-the-Entity-Framework-in-.NET-5).